# Expand All and Collapse All links to handle acitree

Tags: jquery, acitree

I want to create two links: Expand All and Collapse All, that handles the opening and closing of all nodes in aciTree. Can anyone help me solving this? I have found the code to open for seleted node. But I need it for all inodes. Here is the code

```
var api = $('#indvTree').aciTree('api');
var selectedItem = api.selected();
        if (api.isInode(selectedItem)) {
            // this is a tree inode
            if (api.isOpen(selectedItem)) {
                // if already opened
                alert('you need to select a closed inner node\nthe current one is already open');
            } else {
                // open the inner item
                api.open(selectedItem, {
                    uid: 'my-custom-button',
                    success: function(item, options) {
                        var itemId = this.getId(item);
                        alert('a item was just opened, the item ID was ' + itemId);
                    },
                    fail: function(item, options) {
                        var itemId = this.getId(item);
                        alert('failed to open the item with the ID ' + itemId);
                    },
                    _custom_property: 'some-custom-value'
                });
            }
        } else {
            // no selected item or not a tree inode item
            alert('you need to select a closed inner node first');
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating whole code.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the aciTree API with the `expand` and `collapse` properties set so you can avoid walking the entire tree yourself, this way:

```
var openAll = function() {
    var rootChildren = api.children(null);
    var inodes = api.inodes(rootChildren);
    inodes.each(function() {
        // open this node
        api.open($(this), {
            expand: true // to open his childrens too
        });
    });
};

var closeAll = function() {
    var rootChildren = api.children(null);
    var inodes = api.inodes(rootChildren);
    inodes.each(function() {
        // open this node
        api.close($(this), {
            collapse: true // to close his childrens too
        });
    });
};
```

where the `api` is a global variable you got by calling `aciTree('api')` (as in your code).

Then call `openAll` to open all tree nodes and `closeAll` to close them all (handle `onclick` events over your links).